# can not verify google api key- only grid showing- android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use googleAPI. I have tried the following:
1)I have generated a googleAPI key using the keytool and the debug.keystore.
2) I have also generated another key using Myactivity.keystore.

Following these instructions, from fere and other sits:
You'll have to do following things to get it working:

You'll have to generate a MD5 hash of your application debug key
You'll have to provide that MD5 hash to Google while signing up for a map key
Google will then give you a key that you can put in your mapview
This is going to work in these steps:

```
Locate the android debug key in your system. it is found on the following locations depending on your operating system (This path will be useful):
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
Mac OS X and Linux : ~/.android/debug.keystore (where ~ is the path of your home directory.
In a terminal, use the following keytool command to generate the MD5 Hash:
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
Copy the generated hash
Go to : code.google. com/android/maps-api-signup.html (you maybe required to login with your Google account)
Paste the above generated MD5 hash there, accept the Terms and Conditions and click on Generate button
You'll get the API key for your map. paste this in your
When you plan to release the app, generate a release key and repeat the same procedure with the release keys.

Although, all the above steps are exactly what the links contain, but this is a summary.
```

I have tried them both but non of them seems to work. I see only the grid ant in the logcat i get `Couldn't get connection factory client` and through all the search I have done this is a problem with my api key. how should I know that my api key is correct?

Comment: Here, you'll have to use release key instead of api key to display map.

Comment: By release key you mean the one gerated form using keytool and myactivity.keystore not debug? If yes, I have done it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try This to get Correct API key:--

That is the exact path--

```
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\XYZ\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Total path for cmd prompt to get the MD5 fingureprint for the GoogleMap API Key*******

```
D:\eclipse\jre\bin>keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\XYZ\.android\debug.keystore"
```

MD5 fingurePrint will look like this--

```
3E:F4:D6:E6:93:4D:BB:B8:62:3A:A6:0F:E0:FC:4C:65
```

When u get the fingurePrint number afterthat to get the API Key use this link---

```
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html
```

Then u will get API key of your system and can get the Map easily....